# How to access the session information coming in from a third party application in Django

Tags: django, single-sign-on, session-state, django-sessions

I Need to check whether a user is logged in to a third party application from a redirection request that comes from that application. This request must contain a session token and the credentials used to log in to that application. Assuming that they're present, how can I access this information from inside a Django application?

I tried SSO and Django Sessions, however couldn't find anything useful there. It would be really helpful to know if I am looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

if you try

```
print(request.session.session_key)
```

sometimes the result is None. I don't know the reason.
To solve the problem add this code in your view:

```
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
       request.session['cached_session_key'] = request.session.session_key
```

You will always have the session at your disposal.
My apologies if I didn't understand your question

Comment: It somewhat answers my question, but I was looking to access the creds of the user from the session created in another application. Meaning that they would login through another application and I would be able to access the information in my django app so that they can sign in without having to enter credentials again.

Comment: @Apurva Kunkulol I think one way is to use [Django REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/auth-remote-user/#:~:text=In%20Django%2C%20REMOTE_USER%20is %20made,contrib.)
I'm sorry, I don't have the expertise to help you much, I've never used it.